# py2app 'macholib' distribution not found

Tags: python, macos, py2app, mach-o

I am trying to package a python 2.7, tkinter app as a mac standalone using py2app. The app runs properly in alias mode, but generates the following error after building for deployment:

Console output: "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'macholib' distribution was not found and is required by the application"

I ran into an error earlier with macholib. The macholib could not be imported from ctypes.macholib. I fixed this by changing the import statement in **boot**.py to 'from macholib import dyld'.

More information:
 - the app relies on matplotlib and matplotlib-venn
 - I copied /lib/ into myapp.app/contents/ from my anaconda directory to bypass a tcl issue
 - I signed the app from terminal using a mac development certificate and the --deep option